# How to create a 1024x1024 Texture with only one 8-bit value per pixel in Java for Android OpenGL-ES 2.0?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

As the title already says, I'd like to know how to create a 1024x1024 Texture with only one 8-bit value in Java for Android OpenGL-ES 2.0. The reason for this is that I only need it with 8-bit values and don't want to waste the other 24-bits in a RGBA-Texture which would be 4MB instead of 1MB.

The only way I know to set textures in Java is with:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, map, 0);
```

But I don't know if that is of any use here, or if I have to do what I want with a different method or if the only way to achieve this is with the NDK.

I'd like to use that value as alpha for a shader but its not really important what it is, because I can set that in the shader.

Does anyone know how this is possible in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method

```
GLUtils.texImage2D (int target, int level, int internalformat, Bitmap bitmap, int type, int border)
```

allows you to chose the internal texture format.

http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/sig99/advanced99/notes/node51.html

In this web you have the existing formats explained. Btw, **ALPHA8** seems to be the one that fits all the requirements.